# Custom Font Not Working Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to add a custom font to my iOS app and I have followed all the necessary steps(plist, copy build resources etc). The font is working in the Builder Interface but when I run it all that shows up is boxes with ? in them. Please help this has been an issue for almost a week now.
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xJFC.jpg)

Comment: edit code ??? and screenshot of how you set it in IB

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the setup, another pair of eyes could help.

Comment: It is in the Info.plist and what do you mean how I set it in the IB, in font I selected custom and then my font

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: Show how you have it added in Info.plist ... It should look like this (although, if it's the only font you are adding, you'll have only `Item 0`): https://imgur.com/a/JNMXokJ ... It's case-sensitive, so make sure it's spelled correctly and includes the extension.

Comment: I have it in exactly like that. Are you able to run a build of it and see it in the simulator? that is where I find the issue

Comment: @HarrisonPaxton - yep, shows properly for both Simulator and Device. Add this code (I'm assuming you're using Swift) to your `viewDidLoad` func, and make sure `LuckiestGuy-Regular` shows up in the debug console output: https://pastebin.com/gLmGMBcz

Comment: @HarrisonPaxton - ah, I see in comments to an answer that you've done this. Are you setting the text of the label in code? Or in IB? Have you tried creating a new single-view project just to test this? Is it possible you have a faulty font file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you checked Target Membership

[image]

Comment: I did select it and it still wont load when i run the app

Answer (score 0):

From what you described you seemed to have followed the correct steps.

Maybe it's the **font name** that's causing the issue?

According to this tutorial: [Add Custom Fonts To Your App](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

> the font name may not be what you expect. It could be very different
>   than any of the visible font names that you can see

[image]

He says add this code in `viewDidLoad` to of any of your view controllers to find all the font names that your app is currently using. There is a  possibility the font name you entered might be different from the font name the app has it listed as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {

        print("\(family)")
        for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        {
            print("== \(names)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sheesh I don’t know what to say. That’s an odd issue. Wish I could help some more.

Comment: Yeah, the only issue I have is in the build simulator and on my phone, everywhere else the font is installed and working properly

Comment: If it works on your phone you should be good to go. I thought the font wasn’t showing up at all. It’s probably a simulator issue. Did you trying running it on a different version of XCode to see what happens in that version’s simulator? You can always download older or newer XCode versions

Comment: It’s not working on my phone or the simulator and yes I’ve tried different versions of xcode

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299467/question-mark-in-place-of-font-icon-for-some-font-codes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa